# Auto Completion for CSS (Style) in NotePad++

Tags: php, css, notepad++

I use NotePad++ for HTML or PHP editing.

For CSS styles, whether separate or merged in PHP file,
I can only see auto complete words for PHP commands, not style sheet keywords.

Can I make NotePad++ to display these style keywords instead of, or together with PHP commands?

Otherwise, it would be also nice if you recommend any CSS editor instead.

Any help will be appreciated,
thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[Emmet](http://emmet.io/) is an amazing code completion tool, and it seems to integrate with NotePad++ from what I can see: http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/Emmet/